# UICollectionView and UICollectionViewCell not functioning

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I'm trying to create my own custom UICollectionView
For starters, I added a CollectionView to my Storyboard.

[image]

The reason for the PURPLE is because at first I expereinced my contorller not showing at all. So I turned the CELL grey and noticed it was the item not visible after also turning the Collection View purple.

I'm trying to populate my collection view with a unique image and label. This is my beginning of the journey.

Here is my CollectionViewController

```
#import "LoadZoneViewController.h"
#import "ZoneCollectionViewCell.h"

@interface LoadZoneViewController ()

@end

@implementation LoadZoneViewController

static NSString * const reuseIdentifier = @"Cell";

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];



    // Register cell classes
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



#pragma mark <UICollectionViewDataSource>

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
#warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 12;
}


- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
#warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
    return 12;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];



    // Configure the cell

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark <UICollectionViewDelegate>


@end
```

I defined a custom UICollectionViewCell as well, but I thought I should worry about that *after* I fix this issue. The current issue is simply that the label doesn't appear, the View has a scrollbar to the bottom, but I'm not seeing 12 labels.

Comment: try adding  `self.collectionView.delegate = self` and `self.collectionView.dataSource = self` in viewdidload

Comment: Ok I tried that. Still no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding delegates to your class interface

```
@interface LoadZoneViewController ()<UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource>
```

Add this to your `viewDidLoad`

```
[CollView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"ZoneCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"YourCellIdentifier"];
```

And do this is in your `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

```
NSString *identifier = @"YourCellIdentifier";
ZoneCollectionViewCell *cell = (ZoneCollectionViewCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```